# React useEffect called even when dependency hasn't changed

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a parent component where I have a stepper component for a form:

```
<Stepper
    aria-labelledby="stepper-heading"
    activeStep={STEPS[activeStep]}
    onStepChange={(x) => setActiveStep(x)}
    orientation="horizontal"
    className="mb-8"
>
    <Stepper.Step>{capitalize(Stepper.TIMESPAN)}</Stepper.Step>
    <Stepper.Step>{capitalize(Stepper.INCOME)}</Stepper.Step>
    <Stepper.Step>{capitalize(Stepper.RELATIONSHIP)}</Stepper.Step>
    <Stepper.Step>{capitalize(Stepper.DECISION)}</Stepper.Step>
</Stepper>
<FormWrapper setActiveStep={setActiveStep} activeStep={activeStep} personId={personId} />
```

In `FormWrapper` I render components based on an `activeStep` prop:

```
export default function FormWrapper({ activeStep, ...props }: FormWrapperProps) {
    const renderForm = useCallback(() => {
        switch (activeStep) {
            case Stepper. TIMESPAN:
                return <Timespan {...props} />;
            case Stepper. INCOME:
                return <Income {...props} />;
            case Stepper. RELATIONSHIP:
                return <Relationship {...props} />;
            case Stepper. DECISION:
                return <Decision {...props} />;
            default:
                return <Timespan {...props} />;
        }
    }, [activeStep]);

    return renderForm();
}
```

In my `Timespan` component I am fetching data with a `useEffect` with a `personId` set as a dependency:

```
export default function Timespan({ setActiveStep, personId }: CommonFormProps) {
    const [period, setPeriod] = useState<PeriodResponse[]>([]);
    const periodService = new PeriodService();

    useEffect(() => {
        const periodDtoPromises = [getFullYear() - 1, getFullYear() - 2, getFullYear() - 3].map((year) =>
            periodService.getPeriod({
                incomeYear: year.toString(),
                personId,
            })
        );

        Promise.all(periodDtoPromises)
            .then(([period1, period2, period3]) => {
                setPeriod([period1, period2, period3]);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error(error.message);
            });
    }, [personId]);
```

I thought this would make the component only fetch on the first render and then only if `personId` has changed, but as it is even when the `personId` hasn't changed `Timespan` fetches on every render, what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you sure it's not going in default case of your switch statement?

Comment: Yes, I am sure @Mr.Gandhi